# Как сделать разные activity для запросов с разными параметрами HttpGet asp.net Core C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, get

Есть два обработчика, первый должен принимать и обрабатывать ссылку формата

```
https://localhost:44306/Activity/MyActivity
```

а второй с параметром

```
https://localhost:44306/Activity/MyActivity?PortfolioId=1
```

Но беда в том, что всё принимает первый, второй принимает только

```
https://localhost:44306/Activity/MyActivity/{PortfolioID}
```

Т.е. после активити идёт параметр через слеш

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyActivity()
{
    List<Activity> MyAct = db.Activities.Where(x => x.UserId == int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue("Id"))).ToList();
    return View(MyAct);
}


[HttpGet("{PortfolioId}")]
public IActionResult MyActivity(int PortfolioID)
{
    List<Activity> MyAct = db.PortfolioActivities.Include(x => x.Activity).Where(x => x.PortfolioId == PortfolioID).Select(x=>x.Activity).ToList(); //db.Activities.Where(x => x.UserId == int.Parse(User.FindFirstValue("Id"))).ToList();
    return View(MyAct);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверное вам не кажется странным, что разные вещи вы называете одним и тем же словом и если вам предложить все до единого экшены (Create, Add, Delete) назвать одним и тем же словом вы не поймёте юмора.

Тем не менее, вы назвали две разные вещи (MyActivities и ActivitiesFromPortfolio) одним и тем же словом - MyActivity.

И пытаетесь решать не исходную проблему (разные вещи назвали одним и тем же именем), а её дочерние проблемы (как настроить роутинг, чтобы слишком одинаковые url уходили в разные action).

Настоятельно рекомендую решать исходную проблему, а не думать, [как лучше микроскопом забивать гвозди](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4900/213987).

Вот вам вариант:

- https://localhost:44306/Activities/My
- https://localhost:44306/Activityies/Portfolio/{PortfolioID}
- https://localhost:44306/Activityies/User/{UserID}

Вот ещё вариант:

- https://localhost:44306/Activity/MyActivities
- https://localhost:44306/Activity/FromPortfolio/{PortfolioID}
- https://localhost:44306/Activityies/ByUser/{UserID} - ByAuthor, ByOwner...

Это простые варианты, в которых вам даже не придётся задумываться над тем, как технически реализовать подобный роутинг. И ещё они - правильные.

PS "В ИТ всего две реально сложные проблемы: как дать хорошие наименования сущностям и (skipped)"

Comment: кажется мой вопрос был не про то как правильно писать MVC. Я конкретно спросил как разделить активити по параметрам

Comment: @LORD Да, да - я прекрасно понял ваш вопрос (и именно на него и ответил: "никак" и "не надо так делать") и понимаю, что этим комментарием вы настаиваете на своём праве забивать гвозди микроскопом. А вот поняли ли вы мой ответ? Я вот при написании ответа вспоминал про `[ActionName]` и посмотрел нельзя ли как-то выкрутиться из этой ситуации, прежде чем рекомендовать не ходить в эту сторону. Из того тупика в который вы себя загнали одинаковым роутом не выпутаться. И я не настаиваю на галке - можете подождать другого ответа (вдруг таки можно выкрутиться), а этому поставить минус.

Comment: проблема в том, что мне не нужно сделать это в этом проекте, мне нужно узнать как это делать.

Comment: @LORD Ну не получится так сделать. Можно отличить роут с одной переменной от роута с двумя переменными. А у вас ноль переменных и одна переменная - они слишком сливаются, у int есть дефолтное значение  (Вот вы реально понимаете, что у вас роут `"{controller}/{action}/{id}"` и для него маршрут с ID = 0 и с ID = 1 ничем не отличается от маршрута с ID = 2 или ID = 3?) и вы сделали ещё и имена контроллера и экшена одинаковыми. Либо меняйте имена экшенов (как я предложил), либо добавляйте второй параметр (он тут по логике не вяжется).

Comment: маршрут с "{controller}/{action}/{id}" по ID и не должен отличаться, а что насчёт "{controller}/{action}/{id}" и "{controller}/{action}/"

Comment: @LORD Тык, вы с этого начали вопрос: вы получите ошибку, я вам могу даже процитировать: `The current request for action 'MyActivity' on controller type 'HomeController' is ambiguous between the following action methods`, а погуглив её вы будете получать такие же советы, как мой. Вот, например: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26187833/5752652 Вопрос задан 4 года назад и никто не дал другого ответа, думаете с вашим будет иначе?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93602/discussion-between-a-k-and-lord).